# How do I configure ipsec and xl2tpd to not use compression when connecting to VPN?

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, compression, ipsec

I have two config files:

```
./etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd.myvpn_name
./etc/ipsec.d/myvpn_name.conf
```

and somewhere in one of them I need to say "no compression" because I error I get is:

```
Unsupported protocol 'Compression Control Protocol' (0x80fd) received
```

Answer (score 0):

> Unsupported protocol 'Compression Control Protocol' (0x80fd) received

Where did you get this error message? If you get it on the client, it means that the server is sending the 'Compression Control Protocol' (CCP) message and your client can not recognize it. You should enable the CCP on the client so that the negotiation process can continue. By the way, normally when we connect to a Windows VPN server, we need to enable the CCP. Because MPPE is negotiated through the CCP (compression) protocol and not through LCP.

If you get this error message on server side, you have two options:
One is disabling CCP on client side. The other is enabling the CCP on the server side.

I don't know the OS of your VPN server, so I will provide the client side solution.

To enable or disable the CCP on client, just remove or add the "noccp" into the l2tp configuration file. (In your case, it's ./etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd.myvpn_name
)